# Acrobat displays double value in fillable field

Tags: acrobat

Whilst using Acrobat Pro 9, I've created a fillable form and used the "simplified code" to calculate some values.  Then I applied some font formatting and set the field to display in the *number* format and display the currency marker.

Now my form displays the value twice and in both fonts! It does it on every form field, no matter if I've added code or not.

It also doesn't matter whether "Highlight Fields" is enabled.

I tried using different fonts: *Courier Bold*, *Trebuchets* and others and still get the same problem.  You can see in my picture that there the value is repeated "behind the scenes" in a smaller, grayer font.

How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Can you share that for here?

Comment: Excuse me, but I'm not sure what you mean...  It's just the built-in macro-designer...

Comment: I meant can you share that created a fillable form here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after long last and trying to reproduce the error, I think it must have been a rendering issue in Adobe Acrobat.  I can't seem to reproduce it again (it figures), not even in Adobe Reader.

Thanks to whoever took an interest!  I leave this "solution" here in case anyone runs into the same issue.